# Flexbox doesn't work in summary tag

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this pen where the layout is floated, but when I try to flexbox one container below the layout, the flexbox doesn't work. I know it is caused by the floats however, can't find a way to fix it. Tried to use clearfix but it doesnt work.

The items that i'm trying to flex is in summary tag.

---

**Code Snippet:**

```css
summary {
  clear: both;
  padding: 20px;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
}
summary p {
  width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: pink;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<summary class="clearfix">
  <p>Integer eget mauris et urna pulvinar consectetur hendrerit eget mauris. Praesent a interdum justo. Aenean ac diam nec neque fringilla cursus. Donec iaculis tortor in nunc vehicula rutrum. Integer malesuada mollis ligula at varius.</p>
  <p>Integer eget mauris et urna pulvinar consectetur hendrerit eget mauris. Praesent a interdum justo. Aenean ac diam nec neque fringilla cursus. Donec iaculis tortor in nunc vehicula rutrum. Integer malesuada mollis ligula at varius.</p>
  <p>Integer eget mauris et urna pulvinar consectetur hendrerit eget mauris. Praesent a interdum justo. Aenean ac diam nec neque fringilla cursus. Donec iaculis tortor in nunc vehicula rutrum. Integer malesuada mollis ligula at varius.</p>
</summary>
```

---

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/benasl/pen/ALmkxR?editors=1100)

Comment: clear and floats have no effect on flex-box

Comment: how do you want your summary to look like?

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that,the p tags should go in a row

Comment: means each p tag is a row like this [ http://codepen.io/tjbaezid/pen/EgAwxV ] or  want to see those p tags in line like 3 columns ??

Comment: 3 columns in a row

Comment: You posted a useless CSS declaration in your question, and linked a huge bunch of code. You must post a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: @GiedraitytėGreta The problem is that you are using `flexbox` in a `summary` tag, which is **not** a structural one. `summary` is used inside a `details` element.  Consider using a proper semantic tag like `article` or `section` for this, and it will work.

Comment: @Geeky `clear` has no effect in a flex formatting context, but it can affect flex containers which participate in a block formatting context.

Comment: @GiedraitytėGreta Check this [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/jLttn1L2/)...

Comment: Sorry for badly composed questions, my bad. @Ricky_Ruiz method worked. Thank you.

Comment: @GiedraitytėGreta When asking a question, try to provide the **relevant code**, not a link to all your code. This will greatly increase the quality of the answers and solutions you get. I have edited your question this time, but please consider reading the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Oriol provided before asking another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `flexbox` in a [`summary`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary) tag, which is **not** a structural one. `summary` is used inside a `details` element. Consider using a proper semantic tag like `article` or `section` for this, and it will work.

---

**Code Snippet:**

```css
summary,
article {
  display: flex;
}
p::before {
  content: "Paragraph.";
}
details > summary {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<summary>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</summary>

<article>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</article>

<details>
  <summary>Proper Usage</summary>
  <p></p>
</details>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the styles to this classes

```
#wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin:auto;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
display:flex;
flex-direction:column
}
```

and on summary remove clear and display:flex
every thing will work as expected

check this fiddle https://codepen.io/sahithiK/pen/LRqjoR?editors=1100

Hope this helps

Comment: I managed to atchieve the same effect using inline-block with p tags. Ricky_Ruiz mentioned changing the summary tag itself and it worked. Thanks for your help though